# \u0097 character not displayed in RStudio's console or Knitr outputs

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, icu

I'm working on Windows 7 with RStudio.
encoding ISO-8859-1 (System default)

I have got a text file containing long dashes (END OF GUARDED AREA character)
  — 1920 — né à Paris — France —

Here the result in Knitr outputs

```
<U+0097> 1920 <U+0097> né à Paris <U+0097> France <U+0097>
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0097/index.htm

How can I preserve my text in my html and Word outputs?

---

- Here's my file in ANSI

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B91cr4hfMXV4OFdHcF9QN3pkZGM

Works on console but not in html ouptut

---

- Here's my file in utf-8/BOM

-- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B91cr4hfMXV4Vkk5blVkYkUtVVE

Not working in console and HTML output

---

How i read and print the datas in RMarkdown

````
 ```{r}

test1 <- readLines ("dataansi.txt")
print (test1)

```
````

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, please? Otherwise I can only gues: "Something" wrong with the encoding. Is the input file encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: I made some supplements in my question. Thank you for your help